# Comparison of different hashkafas

Tags: sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy

I'm curious whether anyone has published a (reasonably unbiased) comparison of different major hashkafas and the key differences between them.  Has anyone come across such a thing?

To clarify: I'm referring to hashkafas such as "Charedi", "Modern Orthodox", "Religious Zionist" etc - obviously such things are somewhat blurry, but I'm looking for typical key things that someone who subscribes to a specific hashkafa will identify as different to others, but probably not things that non-subscribers will identify it as because I suspect that is likely to be unfairly biased.

Comment: Hashkafas in what? Please clarify.

Comment: @ElonMusk edited

Comment: Who's to say whether it's unbiased or not, aren't we all biased :-)

Comment: @Loani yes, of course, but I mean that the bias in this case hopefully doesn't affect the information, or if it does then it isn't too extreme